# nullPointerException in custom provider for search suggestion

Tags: android, full-text-search, android-sqlite

I want to make a search suggestion with custom provider I follow Google example, searchable dictionary but I got an exception.
Here is my code:

```
public class MyCustomSuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    // UriMatcher stuff
    private static final int SEARCH_CATEGORY = 0;
    private static final int GET_CATEGORY = 1;
    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
    private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private MyDB myDB;
    String TAG = "MyCustomSuggestionProvider";

    public static String AUTHORITY = "com.pooya.autosender.database.MyCustomSuggestionProvider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/"+Constants.DATABASE_NAME);
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        myDB = new MyDB(getContext());
        return false;
    }
    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        // to get definitions...
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, SEARCH_CATEGORY);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, Constants.DATABASE_NAME+"/#", GET_CATEGORY);
        // to get suggestions...
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

        /* The following are unused in this implementation, but if we include
         * {@link SearchManager#SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID} as a column in our suggestions table, we
         * could expect to receive refresh queries when a shortcutted suggestion is displayed in
         * Quick Search Box, in which case, the following Uris would be provided and we
         * would return a cursor with a single item representing the refreshed suggestion data.
         */
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have and format the db query accordingly
        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {

                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
            case SEARCH_CATEGORY:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return search(selectionArgs[0]);
            case GET_CATEGORY:
                return getWord(uri);
            case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
                return refreshShortcut(uri);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                BaseColumns._ID,
                Constants.CATEGORY_NAME,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

        return myDB.getCategoryMatches(query, columns);
    }
    private Cursor search(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                BaseColumns._ID,
                Constants.CATEGORY_NAME};

        return myDB.getCategoryMatches(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
        String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                Constants.CATEGORY_NAME};

        return myDB.getCategory(rowId, columns);
    }

    private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {
      /* This won't be called with the current implementation, but if we include
       * {@link SearchManager#SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID} as a column in our suggestions table, we
       * could expect to receive refresh queries when a shortcutted suggestion is displayed in
       * Quick Search Box. In which case, this method will query the table for the specific
       * word, using the given item Uri and provide all the columns originally provided with the
       * suggestion query.
       */
        String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                BaseColumns._ID,
                Constants.CATEGORY_NAME,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

        return myDB.getCategory(rowId, columns);
    }
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My provider in manifest is:

```
<provider android:name=".database.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"      android:authorities="com.pooya.autosender.database.MyCustomSuggestionProvider" />
```

And my table is:

```
 private static final String CREATE_CATEGOTY_TABLE="CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "+
            Constants.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME+" USING fts4("+
            Constants.CATEGORY_NAME+");";
```

And it is my logcat:

```
10-07 08:24:53.909    1159-1159/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pooya.autosender, PID: 1159
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.UriMatcher.addURI(UriMatcher.java:195)
            at com.pooya.autosender.database.MyCustomSuggestionProvider.buildUriMatcher(MyCustomSuggestionProvider.java:34)
            at com.pooya.autosender.database.MyCustomSuggestionProvider.<clinit>(MyCustomSuggestionProvider.java:20)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 08:25:02.039      389-403/? E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{b210f808 token=Token{b21521d0 ActivityRecord{b223a7c8 u0 com.pooya.autosender/.activity.MainActivity t4}}} timed out
```

Comment: Can you please highlight line no : 195 code ?

Comment: my code has 140 lines ...the problem is at line 34 of my code that is this line : matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, SEARCH_CATEGORY);

Comment: try to check matcher is null before call addURI.

Comment: its not null because i add UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH); before it